# How can I increase parallelism of SBT tests

Tags: playframework, sbt, specs2

I'am aware that SBT runs tasks in parallel by default. When I run our tests the CPU load is less than 50% but as our test are independent and isolated I expect more system load and less time for running the tests.

I'm not sure, but it seems that SBT runs specifications of each test class sequentially but runs test classes in parallel. If true I want everything to be parallel, otherwise I want to increase parallelism of tests.

We use:

- SBT 0.13.8
- Play Framework 2.4
- Specs2

Comment: As far as I can tell, Specs2 should be able to run stuff in parallel: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.6/org.specs2.guide.Execution.html and https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.6/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html (and yes, SBT runs tests in parallel by default too: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html#Disable+Parallel+Execution+of+Tests)

Comment: This is specific to the test framework you are using, rather than being a general SBT thing.